# Android Systrace tool throwing errors

Tags: android, python, systrace

I've been having some performance problems in my Android app's rendering. The official documentation suggested me to use the "systrace" python tool to debug the app, but it's been a pain to use it. I'm using the suggested command:

```
python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html gfx
```

First I had to install some missing python dependencies using pip (like pywin32) otherwise it wouldn't run. Now it's giving me some runtime errors in the code, like:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I'm using python 2.7.15, windows 7 64bit, device android version is 6.0.1

Comment: Im facing the issue Windows 10

Comment: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-perf-testing/issues/44

Comment: I had the same bug and managed to get the systrace working via Android Device Monitor. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152752/1683241